# Construct adj matrix in Tensorflow with adj list

Tags: tensorflow

my model requires an adjacency matrix, which is currently created in numpy and passed to tensorflow as a placeholder.

With growing problem size, the I/O between Memory and VRAM is a bottleneck I suppose as the complexity is quadratic. For e.g. I use dim 400, which will result in 160.000 matrix values.

As the adj matrix is sparse, I thought about passing a adj list and then creating the adj matrix in tf on GPU.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow support sparse placeholder. In this page https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_placeholder
there is an example showing how to use `tf.sparse_placeholder`